# PHP MYSQL Attach textarea text to email

Tags: php, html, mysql, attachment

I'm working on a PHP MYSQL project Job board which requires me to upload or save CV into database.

I would like to attach text from a textarea (CV) field to an email and send to user.

How can I attach textarea text as a doc and send it with email?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for.  What exactly is a CV - are you talking about a resume?  How does this question relate to PHP, MySQL, or HTML?  How do you want to use these technologies to solve your problem?

Comment: Are you saying you want to send an email from PHP with an attachment which is: a text file? a Microsoft Word document?

Comment: I have a textarea where i copy and past my CV (resume) and send it to employer as a attachment with my email and also save into mysql database.

Comment: At the moment i can include the CV (resume) into my email which makes the email too long so i like add this CV (resume) as attachment. I'm using PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the CV from the database and save to tmp folder. Use a mail library such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swift Mailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/) to compose and add the attachment.

Using one of these email libraries greatly simplifies the process. For instance, using PHPMailer, sending an email would comprise:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->From = 'my@email.com'; 
$mail->Mailer   = 'smtp';
$mail->Subject  = 'A Subject';
$mail->Body     = 'Here\'s the CV!';
$mail->AddAddress('someones@email.com');
$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/cv.zip', 'cv.zip');
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: I can do that but i like to put it as attachment not include in the email.

Comment: This does do it as an attachment, not in email.

Comment: I tried this but it only include in body of email but not as attachment. I like to convert textarea into MS Document.

Comment: @Majid - Take a look at PHPWord (http://phpword.codeplex.com/) if you want to create a MS Word document from within a PHP script

Comment: @Majid: Your mail client may be displaying attachments as inline. If that's the case, that is a function of the client and cannot be affected by the sender.

Comment: @If you want to do it as an MS word doc, write it as HTML then save it with a .doc extension. Believe it or not, this will work.